# How can I use select function to obtain numeric columns?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

I have a data frame called `df` containing a variable `Bw` for bodyweight. I used the following the select it:

```
Bw <- df %>% select(1)
```

But the `Bw` is the type of `data.frame`.

I looked up the usage of `select` function and didn't find some options that allow me to do so. Also, `as.numeric()` seems not working either.

Is there any way it can be converted to `numeric` type?

Comment: I think you need  `df %>% pull(1)`

Comment: Your question title was `How can I use select function to obtain numeric columns`.  It implies to select for numeric type columns